# ASP.NET Session State Errors when redirecting to page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

So I have this code that sets a session and redirects to another page:

```
Protected Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    Dim CredentialsValid = Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)

    If (CredentialsValid) Then
        'Add User Session stuff
        Session.Add("MFUserName", UserName.Text)
        Session.Add("MFPW", Password.Text)
        Response.Redirect("MFACheck.aspx", False)
    Else


    End If

End Sub
```

When stepping through the code, I land on MFACheck.aspx, which has this code behind:

```
Public Class MFACheck

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim UserName = Session.Item("MFUserName")
Dim pw = Session.Item("MFPW")
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


End Sub
```

I am getting an error when I hit this line in MFACheck.aspx

```
 Dim UserName = Session.Item("MFUserName")
```

The error states that

```
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
```

The problem is that I seem to satisfy each of these requirements. Here is the page directive on MFACheck.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/NoNav.Master" CodeBehind="MFACheck.aspx.vb" Inherits="REDACTEDFORSOPOST" EnableSessionState="true" %>
```

Also, under system.web in my web.config, I have this:

```
<sessionState 
        timeout="30"
        mode="InProc"
        cookieless ="false"/>
```

And under system.webServer, I have this

```
<modules>
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
</modules>
```

What am I missing? I seem to have all of the requirements to read my session on MFACheck.aspx, why does the page give me an error?

Thank you for your help/

Comment: Put it in the httpModules section?

Answer (score 0):

As @Kramb wrote in a comment, it seems you need to add the `module` registration over here:

```
<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>
```

The `web.config` schema and where to put what depends on the version of the web server where your application is running. In older versions of `IIS` and also (I think) in the `Cassini` server used for local debugging in older versions of `Visual Studio`, the `modules` and `handlers` are registered directly under `<system.web>`. In newer version they are under `<system.webServer>`.

In this case, it seem like the environment you use expects them to be under `<system.web>`, so add them there.